# Showing only the substrings of COMPREPLY bash completion options to the user

Tags: bash, bash-completion

In a bash completion script, suppose `COMPREPLY=(aa/ba/ aa/bb/)`. When the script is invoked, the completion options looks like this to the user:

```
$ foo aa/b<TAB>
aa/ba/
aa/bb/
```

However, I want to have a bit more control over how these options are displayed. In particular, I want to show only a substring of each COMPREPLY option to the user, similar to how directory completion works in bash now:

```
$ foo aa/b<TAB>
ba/
bb/
```

Is there any way of doing this in bash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having the same problem and I fixed it by adjusting how I bound the completion function to the command. I know this works when you are dealing with actual files in the filesystem, I think it will work with any sort of file path like options, but I'm not sure.

Before:

```
complete -F _fubar fubar
```

After:

```
complete -o filenames -F _fubar fubar
```

For more details: [Programmable Completion Builtins](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Programmable-Completion-Builtins)

Comment: Awesome! Now I just need to figure out how to selectively turn on/off options for different `COMPREPLY` cases in my function, *without* using `compopt`

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code taken from debian sid /etc/bash_completion should help:

```
# Remove colon-word prefix from COMPREPLY items
local colon_word=${1%${1##*:}}
local i=${#COMPREPLY[*]}
while [ $((--i)) -ge 0 ]; do
    COMPREPLY[$i]=${COMPREPLY[$i]#"$colon_word"}
done
```

Comment: Thanks enzotib. Unfortunately this technique doesn't work, because then the substring replaces the entire completion. That is, `foo aa/b<TAB>` becomes `foo ba/` :-(